# Distance Function for SQLite in iOS 5 is very slow

Tags: sqlite, ios5, distance, latitude-longitude

I have been using for a long time a C function that calculates the distance between coordinates in SQLLite.

The thing is that for the very same database and different iOS devices (4 and 5) the time for executing the same query is 5 times longer when running iOS 5.

Does anybody knows why?

Here's the code for the distance:

```
static void distanceFunc(sqlite3_context *context, int argc, sqlite3_value **argv){
// check that we have four arguments (lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)
assert(argc == 4);

// check that all four arguments are non-null
if (sqlite3_value_type(argv[0]) == SQLITE_NULL || sqlite3_value_type(argv[1]) == SQLITE_NULL || sqlite3_value_type(argv[2]) == SQLITE_NULL || sqlite3_value_type(argv[3]) == SQLITE_NULL) {
    sqlite3_result_null(context);
    return;
}

// get the four argument values
double lat1 = sqlite3_value_double(argv[0]);
double lon1 = sqlite3_value_double(argv[1]);
double lat2 = sqlite3_value_double(argv[2]);
double lon2 = sqlite3_value_double(argv[3]);

// convert lat1 and lat2 into radians now, to avoid doing it twice below
double lat1rad = DEG2RAD(lat1);
double lat2rad = DEG2RAD(lat2);

// apply the spherical law of cosines to our latitudes and longitudes, and set the result appropriately
// 6378.1 is the approximate radius of the earth in kilometres
sqlite3_result_double(context, (acos(sin(lat1rad) * sin(lat2rad) + cos(lat1rad) * cos(lat2rad) * cos(DEG2RAD(lon2) - DEG2RAD(lon1))) * 6378.1) * 1000); }
```

and here's a example on how I am using it:

```
Select distance(Latitude, Longitude,-22.89095,-47.05134) from TABLE
```

Please, any help will be very appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK.
I have figured out it's an issue on iOS 5.0
Even with the final release the slow querys were still happening.

I had to remove the "`order by distance(Latitude, Longitude,-22.89095,-47.05134)`" and the query got faster again.

Then I did the sorting using code...
Not the best way. but...

Answer (score 0):

iOS 5 is still a beta, and performance on beta builds are not generally a good performance benchmark.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same experience with CoreData (using sqllite container).

Prior to IOS5, having a NSFetchRequest with sortDescriptors worked at a reasonable speed.

After the upgrade to 5, a very noticable delay. Setting the sortDescriptors to an empty array corrected the poor performance, but meant that I needed to manually sort (and group) my results in code.

Was hoping the 5.0.1 update would fix it, but it still seems a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add indexes. Even with this change, it still runs slower than it did before. I've run through all of the settings and it seems to be something else - the version of sqlite is the same. A mystery.